# Strip Youtube Link from URL

Tags: php, regex, parsing, youtube, strip

I own a website which allows users to download Youtube videos. I need php scripts which detects if a youtube url is present, like:

givemeyoutube.com takes users to my normal website but if they type,

www.givemeyoutube.com/watch?v=OZLUa8JUR18

how do I take them to the index of my website and strip out the "watch?v=OZLUa8JUR18" and store it as a variable?

**UPDATE:** How can I do it so that it checks URL and if it contains "watch?v=" then redirect to another page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use preg_match with the following regular expression

`/(\/watch\?v=)([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/`

Answer (score 1):

Preg match with `\b(?<=v.|/)[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{11,}\b` as RegExp

Answer (score 1):

You can to use `mod_rewrite` to properly take care of a request like `watch?V=123456`

in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^watch index.php [QSA]
```

then in `index.php`:

```
if( isset( $_GET['v'] ) ) {
    // access the v parameter with $_GET['v'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think url rewriting would be better suited for this task, as you need to rewrite the url anyway to make sure that `watch` opens an actual php page.

I would use something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^watch.*$ /index.php?action=watch [QSA]
```

This rule would cause all requests that start with `watch` to be routed to `index.php` with the original query string (due to `[QSA]`) and an additional parameter called `action` with the value `watch`.

Comment: What do these do:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d


#if in subdirectory RewriteBase /subdirectory/index.php
RewriteRule (.+)? /indekx.php [L]

Comment: @Jack Brown These are necessary if you rewrite everything, not just requests starting with `watch`. They make sure that existing files and directories don't get rewritten, only urls to pages that don't exist.